port actively refused requests
I run Mapproxy with waitress on several windows servers in different environments (different Hardware, VM).
On a virtual Server we face the problem, that some requests to waitress are failing. Using K6 for loadtesting turns out, that if 230 virtual users send one request at the once some requests are failing with this error:
WARN[0000] Request Failed error="Get \"http://127.0.0.1:9650/tiles/1.0.0/mymap/webmercator/x/x/x.png\": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9650: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

If I send this 230 requests over and over again for 10sec, that generates around 10'000 Requests, the cpu utilization is at around 30%. But in this case only on the first 230 Requests some are refused, after that all requests the a respons.
I use the exactly same configuration of waitress on all windows servers:
call waitress-serve --listen 127.0.0.1:9650 --threads 500 --connection-limit 1000 --backlog 4096 config:application

As I use the same configuration on all Windows Server and on other I can send 500 requests with K6 without problems, it seems to me that windows must somehow limit the number of concurent requests on this port.
Some research pointed me to the backlog of the port and to add MaxUserPort and TcpTimeWaitDelay to the registry:
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters but this did not change anything.
Some Information about the server:

Windows Server 2022 Datacenter
VMWare7.1
Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6342 CPU @ 2.80GHz, 2793 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 2 Logical Processor(s)

My Questions to understand this issue better:

What does limit the numbers of concurrent connections to a port? Is it the Hardware (CPU, ..) or Windows or something else?
If it is Windows, can the numbers of concurrent connections to a port be changed?

all hints to solve this problem are very welcome.
